# ¿Como acceder a los atributos de un Object[] para crear una clase propia?

Tags: java, netbeans, object, cast

programando en Java me ha surgido el siguiente problema, no puedo realizar un Cast de un Object[] a mi clase Benefactor.

1.Partiendo que tengo un JTable accedo a la fila de la tabla que selecciono y creo un objeto **Object[]** para coger todos los atributos (nombre,apellido,telefono,nif,poblacion,fechaNacimiento,domicilio,cuentaBancaria,totalDonado).

```
int filaSeleccionada = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
Object benefactor[] = new Object[]{dtm.getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, 0),dtm.getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, 1),dtm.getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, 2),dtm.getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, 3),dtm.getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, 4),dtm.getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, 5),dtm.getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, 6)};
```

2. Tengo una clase Benefactor que está relacionado con otra clase Amigo (Solo pongo los atributos para poneros en situación).

   ```
   public class Benefactor {
   private Amigo amigo;
   private Ingreso ingreso;
   private String cuentaBancaria;
   private float totalDonado;
   }
   public class Amigo {
   private Voluntario voluntario;
   private Adoptante adoptante;
   private Collection acogedors;
   private Benefactor benefactor;
   private String nombre;
   private String apellido;
   private int telefono;
   private String nif;
   private String poblacion;
   private Date fechaNacimiento;
   private String domicilio;
   }
   ```
3. El Error Exception que me sale es 
   *Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to modelo.Benefactor*

El objetivo final de todo es conseguir acceder a los atributos que tengo en la tabla y pasarlos todos mediante un método el cuál espera un parametro Object, obtener los datos para generar mi propio Benefactor y Amigo con su respectivo constructor. Un saludo, gracias de antemano.

```
// método desde el que inicia todo
usuario.nuevoIngreso(sFecha, importe, observaciones, benefact);
// método en el que ya tengo acceso a la clase Benefactor
protectora.nuevoIngreso(fecha, importe, observacin, benefactor);
// por lo que sería fácil si fuera un sencillo cast tal que así:
Benefactor benefactor = (Benefactor) benefact;
```

Answer (score 1):

Realmente no me queda muy claro qué quieres hacer, explico un par de errores de tu explicación:

1. Lo que estás creando no es un `Object`, es un `Object[]` (un array de `Object`). Como tal, no accederías a los **atributos** sino a los distintos elementos del array.

   Aparte parece que crees que puedes crear un objeto de una clase y añadirle dinámicamente atributos igual que se puede hacer en, por ejemplo, Javascript. En Java eso no se puede hacer; si creas una instancia de `Object` tendrás los atributos y métodos definidos en la clase `Object` y ninguno más.
2. Una vez creada una instancia de una clase, siempre es de esa clase. La puedes asignar a una variable de una superclase, pero no de una subclase. Ten en cuenta que (para asignaciones) lo que importa es la clase de la instancia, no de la variable.

   ```
   Object obj = new Object();
   String str = (String) obj;   // Mal, lo que creaste fue un Object

   String str1 = new String("Hola");
   Object obj = str1;       // Object es superclase
   String str2 = (String) str1;  // Lo que creaste es un String así que la asignación es válida.
   ```